# hive rows preceding unexpected behavior

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Given this ridiculously simple data set:

```
+--------+-----+
| Bucket | Foo |
+--------+-----+
|      1 | A   |
|      1 | B   |
|      1 | C   |
|      1 | D   |
+--------+-----+
```

I want to see the value of Foo in the previous row:

```
select
foo,
max(foo) over (partition by bucket order by foo rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding) as prev_foo
from
...
```

Which gives me:

```
+--------+-----+----------+
| Bucket | Foo | Prev_Foo |
+--------+-----+----------+
|      1 | A   | A        |
|      1 | B   | A        |
|      1 | C   | B        |
|      1 | D   | C        |
+--------+-----+----------+
```

Why do I get 'A' back for the first row? I would expect it to be be null. It's throwing off calculations where I'm looking for that null.  I can work around it by throwing a `row_number()` in there, but I'd prefer to handle it with fewer calcs.

Comment: It seems like a bug in windowing function. Why don't you just use the `LAG(foo) OVER(partition by bucket order by foo) ` instead?

Comment: Lag works perfectly, thanks!  Somehow I didn't know I could use lag with Hive.  Post this as answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the LAG function to get previous row:

```
LAG(foo) OVER(partition by bucket order by foo) as Prev_Foo
```